# Performance Issue using Restkit (vs. TBXML)

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, core-data, restkit

I want to use RestKit to parse XML data from our servers. Downloading and parsing takes 2-3 seconds with our current approach using [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk). However, when I now download and parse the same XML using RestKit + CoreData it takes ~ 10 seconds. Which is way too much in our case since it would drastically affect the end user experience.

The XML has a size of 1.3 MB and I convert the XML to two entities with the following attributes:

Parent:

- 3 string attributes
- 1 Integer32 attribute

Nested Object:

- 2 date attributes (With a custom Date formatter assigned to the mapping: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'`)
- 2 string attributes

Is there a way with which I could boost the performance of my setup and is the trade-off of CoreData quite big so that it might make sense to only use RestKit without CoreData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges.  Downloading and parsing with TBXML is doing significantly less than RestKit + CoreData, which is downloading, parsing, dynamically mapping to objects and storing to CoreData.

[This article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) gives a good overview of the performance characteristics of various XML parsers running on iOS devices.  TBXML is the fastest, with libxml2 DOM parsing about 20% slower.